# Is it possible to find Firefox 4 packaged with all necessary libraries?

Tags: firefox, debian

I am on a work computer that is on debian etch and I need Firefox 4. I am not sudo. I have successfully installed Firefox 3.6 with the necessary libraries locally before but since I lost that folder I was really hoping I could switch to Firefox 4.

I have been having a lot more trouble than I thought I would and I'd like to know if there is anywhere on the net where I could get an archive that included Firefox 4 and all the necessary libraries (gtk, libdus and such).

Comment: guessing you have not tried the official download page... http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/new/

Answer (score 0):

Normally those libraries aren't distributed because they are provided by all systems.  If yours are too old your only option will be to grab them from another PC, perhaps running a newer version of Debian.  You can see which libraries are used by running:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ldd firefox-bin
```

In the Firefox folder.  Actually running Firefox will probably print errors about incompatible libraries too.  All you need to do is copy them from another PC into the same directory as firefox-bin and the other distributed library files.

Alternatively you could install Firefox on a PC where it works and use [Statifier](http://statifier.sourceforge.net/) or [Ermine](http://www.magicermine.com/features.html) to create a static binary which you can then transfer back to your locked-down box.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the .tar.gz binary package directly from Mozilla's website http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/fx/ . This works fine and doesn't require root privileges.